# How to use aws s3 sync from the CLI for more than 1000 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm attempting syncing the contents of an S3 bucket (actually digital ocean space) to my local hard drive with aws-cli s3 sync or aws-cli s3 cp --recursive

I've tried using both the aws-cli `sync` and `cp` commands, but both stop after 1000 objects. I know sync mentions it's limited to 1000 objects with the --page-size flag (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), but it seems like everything I've seen talks about syncing entire buckets, but my sync's stop at 1000 objects and I have 7 million to sync.

```
aws s3 cp s3://MYBUCKET ~/Documents/temp_space --source-region https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com --profile MYPROFILE --endpoint=https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com --recursive
```

```
aws sync cp s3://MYBUCKET ~/Documents/temp_space --source-region https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com --profile MYPROFILE --endpoint=https://sfo2.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

I expect to be able to sync the entire bucket, not just sync 1000 objects.

Comment: Have you tried to do this, or is your question based on reading the docs only? I just uploaded 52,348 objects using ‘’’aws s3 cp —recursive —quiet . s3://my-bucket’’’ which took about 20 minutes.

Comment: Perhaps this is a limitation of Digital Ocean?

Answer (score 1):

The ‘’’—page-size’’’ parameter limits the number or results in a request, not the total number.

By way of example, in a scenario where you have a directory with 5,000 objects that you wish to copy to a s3 bucket. Your command would look something like `aws s3 cp . s3://your-bucket`. This will copy all contents of our current directory, 5,000 objects, to our s3 bucket.

The default (and maximum) `—page-size` is 1,000 objects so, because we haven’t specified a `—page-size`, in order to accomplish copying all 5,000 objects to your s3 bucket, under the hood, the AWSCLI is going to handle making 5 requests (5 x 1,000 objects) to copy all 5,000 objects.

Generally, you should be able to simply ignore this optional parameter and run your `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync` without issue. If you face issues with the request timing out, then you can add the `—page-size` parameter with a value less than 1,000 to address the time-out issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a short, you can use https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd to replace the aws cli.

The v1 of s3 list-objects API returns 1000 entries at the max and a `marker` can be used to the next query. But the `aws cli s3 sync` doesn't support `marker` for some reason.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html

The v2 of s3 list-objects API uses a `ContinuationToken` to replace the `marker`. `aws cli` works with v2 better.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

For DigitalOcean the version 2 list type is not currently supported.

- https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/spaces/#list-bucket-contents
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/digitalocean-spaces-cannot-download-directory-with-more-than-1000-files

So you have to use s3cmd.