# S3 - How many files can be copied/synced in a single command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm trying to copy/sync thousands of files (approximately 700GB) from S3 to an external server, but there seems to be a limit on how many files can be copied during a single command since `cp` and `sync` don't copy all the files (only ~670MB are copied), and since every time I rerun the `cp` command, the very same files are copied. On the other hand, rerunning `sync` command does nothing, it does not proceed and copy the remaining files, it finishes as it has already synced all files from S3 (which it didn't).

I only have success copying files if I use `mv` command, which makes sense since it copies and then deletes the files.

**QUESTIONS**

How many files can be copied during a single command (`s3 cp s3://my_bucket /my/own/server`)?

Is there a way to run a single command that will copy **all** files/dirs? How?

**ENVIRONMENT**

**OS**: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

**AWS-CLI**: aws-cli/1.18.108 Python/3.6.9 Linux/4.15.0-39-generic botocore/1.17.31

I have already read the documentation, but it didn't seem to clear about this specific matter (although it seems that it only processes 1 thousand files/time)

I also have seen answers ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57597012/how-to-use-aws-s3-sync-from-the-cli-for-more-than-1000-objects/62862279#62862279) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57600354)) at StackOverflow that suggests that the limit of a single cp command is 1,000 files. But I wanted a final answer on this matter.

**EDIT**

After running this command: `aws s3 ls --recursive --human-readable --summarize s3://my_bucket > /home/aws-s3-ls.out`

I got this result:

[image: AWS S3 copies a maximum of 1,000 files/time]

So, it looks to me that it can copy 1,000 files each time.

Now I want to know if there is a simple way to bypass it. Adding a parameter that will force it to copy all files. I'm not necessarily interested in third-party utilities, but I accept them if it's not possible without them.

Comment: I would have imagined that `cp` and `sync` would copy _all_ files, but they could become confused with large numbers of files (eg running out of memory, or bucket listings taking too long to complete). If a file is copied via `sync`, it (normally?) won't be copied again because the size and date already match. You might need to break-down the task into smaller chunks by only copying a particular Prefix (directory) at a time, at least for the initial copy.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  I didn't mention in the question because I thought it was obvious. But sync command didn't copy twice the same files. It simply doesn't proceed to copy the missing files. If I rerun sync it does nothing as it thinks it has already copied all files. I did edit the question to address your comment.

Comment: My understanding is that `aws s3 sync` compares the source directory and destination directory, then uses the Date and Length of a file to determine whether to copy a file. It does not maintain its own 'list' of files that have previously been copied. Are you wanting to include sub-directories in the copy? If so, be sure to include `--recursive` in your command. Also, please note that `sync` is **one-directional**. If you want to sync files in the other direction, it needs to be run again with the parameters reversed.